# How paranoid do I have to be between petting a stray cat and playing with my own?

Tags: cats, health, diseases, feral

There's a local semi-feral who actively comes over to say hello when she sees me, and has been doing so since well before my own kids moved in. I can't resist giving her a skritch when she does so, and of course she'll rub against my ankles if she gets the chance.

I try to remember to wash my hands thoroughly afterward, on the same principle as a doctor washing between patients... but id like to have a better sense of just how transmissable car diseases are via a human vector.

Does anyone happen to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some illnesses, like [feline distemper](http://www.petmd.com/cat/conditions/infectious-parasitic/c_ct_feline_panleukopenia), [ring worm](http://pets.thenest.com/diseases-worry-stray-cat-10488.html), and [feline leukemia](http://pets.webmd.com/cats/facts-about-feline-leukemia-virus) can be passed on via saliva and other contact-specific vectors.  As long as you wash your hands (and anywhere else the feral cat touches) thoroughly and keep your cats vaccinated, you should be fine.

Comment: Specifically look out for blood, urine, feces, saliva, and -- to a lesser extent --  dander.